# What are the historic OS X versions' 'selling lines'?

Tags: macos, history

[OS X 10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) [is advertised](http://www.apple.com/macosx/) on the Apple website as

> The world's most advanced desktop operating system advances even
>   further

The beta page for [OS X 10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) [goes](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/):

> The world's most advanced desktop operating system moves even further
>   ahead

I was wondering what the previous OS X version were advertised as, as Apple just seems to recycle the same mantra. Is this somewhere available online?

Comment: Wikipedia is a good place for this sort of knowledge curation. Are you facing a problem that you are trying to solve here? Feel free to edit that into the question and it can easily be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a list of Apple slogans.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apple_Inc._slogans) A good portion down is OS X slogans.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, thanks for pointing that out. As always, feel free to suggest edits to any other of my posts that have errors in them.